What kind of Schengen visa is this?
This person wonders, if he is allowed to leave the country stated on his visa. Romania is a Schengen member, soon full schengen member. But I think schengen visas say "SCHENGEN STATES" on them, while this one say "ROMANIA":

I know that some schengen visas can exclude certain countries, by appending for example -FR if France is not allowed. The link in this official FAQ 404s.
I can't see exancrly what is written on this visa here.
Is this a national only visa, only allowing travel to Romania and nothing else? Why does it say "90" on the right (presumably days?) yet it seems to be valid for more than 4 months? And it says D (usually long term?) and PERMANENT, so residence? But if its residencde, why isn't it a card?
What does the D/AM/ROU2 mean?

This is a type D visa. Those are country-specific.

This is not a Schengen Visa (Type C), but a National Visa (Type D). Such visas, depending on the county, are issued so that you can enter to take up residence. After your arrival a residence permit will then be issued.

The strangest thing in my opinion is the number of entries. Two-entry visas were originally designed to allow touristic visits to the UK and Ireland in the middle of a trip to the Schengen area, I don't know why you would restrict the number of entries for a long-stay visa. And if you did, why would you still allow an extra entry instead of just one??

@Relaxed then why do they never give extra entries to first time applicants? How does having extra entries help you abuse the system or what is the limitation trying to prevent?

@user1721135 The notion is that a first time (short-stay) visa is issued for a specific trip and you only get a multiple-entry visa after using several of these restrictive visas correctly. Obviously if you intend to stay illegally and are prepared to face the consequences, it really doesn't prevent anything. And it makes even less sense for a long-stay visa where immigration is explicitly the purpose…

This is a national Romanian visa. Such visas are supposed to be issued for stays longer than 90 days and are not technically “uniform visas” regulated by the Schengen Visa code but do have some impact on travel to other Schengen countries. They are also called “long-stay visas” in the Schengen acquis and EU literature.

Is this a national only visa, only allowing travel to Romania and nothing else?

It is primarily valid in Romania but also exempts the holder from any visa requirement for visits to the Schengen area as provided by article 6(1)(b) of the Schengen Borders code (regulation 2016/399). It should not be used for visits to the Schengen area if the holder does not intend to take up residence in Romania. It also relaxes some other entry rules when the holder is in transit to Romania, see article 6(5)(a).

Why does it say "90" on the right (presumably days?) yet it seems to be valid for more than 4 months?

The “90” is a bit ambiguous but the standard visa sticker requires putting something there. For short-stay visas, it is indeed a number of days less than or equal to 90. Other countries write “XXX” for long-stay visas.
Irrespective of what's written in the field, there are a few things to keep in mind:

Visits to other Schengen countries are in principle limited to 90 days in any 180-day period. If the holder wants to stay longer in a Schengen country other than Romania, they are supposed to apply for a local national visa or residence permit instead.
Romania may impose other restrictions including a requirement to apply for a permit within a certain time of entering or a maximum period of stay out of the country before the visa loses its validity.
Length of stay and period of validity are always considered separately in the Schengen area.

I do not know anything about Romanian rules and practices but taking all this into account, one interpretation could for example be that the holder is allowed to enter Romania with an eye towards permanent stay at any time between October 28 and April 12 but has to apply for another document within 90 days. Or the 90 is only a reminder of the maximum stay rules for visits to other Schengen countries while staying in Romania on this visa.

And it says D (usually long term?) and PERMANENT, so residence? But if its residence, why isn't it a card?

There are exceptions but it's very common for Schengen countries to only issue residence cards after you have actually established residence and can provide an address in the country. Furthermore, many countries restrict applications for residence permits to the holders of a specific category of visas, i.e. it is not allowed to apply for a residence permit on foot of a visitor's visa, as explained in the answers to your earlier question Getting a long term job in Schengen and ID card while on a short term visa?
So in practice you would often need a visa like this one before being able to apply for a card (D indeed means ”long stay”, which includes anything longer than 90 days). Once you have the card, it replaces the visa but you would not be able to get the card if you didn't have a long-stay visa in the first place.
Sometimes, the visa has a validity longer than 3 months so it is not necessary to apply for a permit immediately after moving. In principle, a country could also keep renewing a long-stay visa instead of issuing a plastic card to long-term residents but I don't know any that does. Switzerland and Italy recently had permits that looked like little booklets but I think they are also moving towards plastic credit-card-format permits. All of these are essentially equivalent as far as Schengen rules are concerned.

D/AM/ROU2

This is a code related to the purpose or restrictions attached to the visa. Other countries use similar codes or plain language annotations, I am not aware of any EU-wide standard.
In Romania, “D/AM” stands for an employment visa and “lucrator” also means “worker”.

It (the "90") is not ambiguous at all. You must (depending on the country) apply for or have recieved a residence permit that allows you to stay longer than the given amount of days (which can be less than 90) given in the D-Visa, otherwise you must leave.

@MarkJohnson It's not that simple and there is no basis for your interpretation as these visas are not grounded in EU law. The field has no obvious meaning when it comes to long-stay visas, which is why it's usually left unused. I could detail why but honestly a sentence with a bold “or” and a parenthesis that reads “(depending on the country)” basically proves my point even before getting into all the other possible interpretations…
